# How to trigger azure Databricks notebook from Apache Airflow

Tags: airflow, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows

I have created some ETL in Azure data bricks notebook.
Now trying to execute that notebook from the airflow-1.10.10.

If anyone can help it would be great.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow [includes native integration with Databricks](https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/airflow/providers/databricks), that provides 2 operators: `DatabricksRunNowOperator` & `DatabricksSubmitRunOperator` (package name is different depending on the version of Airflow.  There is also an [example of how it could be used](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/databricks/example_dags/example_databricks.py).

You will need to create a connection with name `databricks_default` with login parameters that will be used to schedule your job.  In simplest case, for job you just need to provide a definition of the cluster, and notebook specification (at least path to notebook to run), something like this:

```
    notebook_task_params = {
        'new_cluster': new_cluster,
        'notebook_task': {
            'notebook_path': '/Users/airflow@example.com/PrepareData',
        },
    }
    # Example of using the JSON parameter to initialize the operator.
    notebook_task = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
        task_id='notebook_task',
        json=notebook_task_params
    )
```

P.S. There is an [old blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/07/19/integrating-apache-airflow-with-databricks.html) with announcement of this integration.

Comment: How it will communicate between Databricks and Airflow. Do we need to pass workspace id or token somewhere in airflow? Also how we will pass the parameter from airflow to data bricks notebook.

Comment: I wrote in the asnwer "create a connection with name `databricks_default` with login parameters that will be used to schedule your job".  Please look into linked example & blog post as well